# の要領で as "in the same way as"/"in the manner of" vs. のように

Tags: words, nuances

Full text is [over here](http://www.yomiuri.co.jp/gourmet/food/burari/20120915-OYT8T00397.htm).

This is part of the description of how 茄子餃子{なすぎょうざ} is prepared at a particular restaurant:

> 天ぷらの要領で水で溶いた小麦粉をつけて中火の油で揚げる。

If の要領で was replaced by のように, would there be any difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there would be small difference. `要領` often implies a process which consists of multiple steps or involves some special "technique", while `のように` does not imply that at all. However, this difference is very small.